# Is it possible to reduce aLR parser's states by using DFA minification algorithm?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Well, when I learnt Regular Grammar and Regular Expression, the last step of constructing a DFA is to minimize the states by applying the *Hapcroft Algorithm*. Now I am reading the purple dragon book about the LR parsing. Oddly it didn't mention the LR(0) automata, which is  a DFA, can be further optimized with the minification algorithm. It is just not neccessary (like the final DFA is promised to be a minimized DFA), or it is impossible to do it?

Comment: not sure about LR(0), it doesn't have a lot of states in the first place. it is possible to perform minimization for [LR(1)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258746690_An_LR_parser_with_less_states) parsers, but then there are already much better options (SLR(1), LALR(1)). the automaton construction takes a lot of time in the first place and minimizing it will take even more time.

Comment: It is a DPDA, not a DFA, surely?